# ROS2 how to programmatically set rosout logging handler

Tags: ros, ros2, rosout, logger

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In ROS2 there are different types of logging handlers.

Command line arguments can be used to setup the loggers: these are passed to `rclcpp::init()` and then to `rcl::init()`.
The command line arguments can do the following: enable stdout logging, enable rosout logging, enable an external logging library (log4cxx or spdlog).
They do this by creating a `logging_multiple_output_handler` and setting it through `rcutils_logging_set_output_handler`.

I found myself in a situation where I want to use my own version of `logging_multiple_output_handler`.
These handler should always use 2 loggers: rosout and an additional one that I'm defining.

For this reason, I created a function to be called right after `rclcpp::init` in order to re-initialize the logging handlers to what I need.

```
void set_ros2_logger_handler()
{

  auto allocator = rcl_get_default_allocator();
  rcl_logging_rosout_init(&allocator);

  auto logging_multiple_output_handler =
  [](
    const rcutils_log_location_t * location,
    int severity, const char * name, rcutils_time_point_value_t timestamp,
    const char * format, va_list * args) -> void
    {
        rcl_logging_rosout_output_handler(location, severity, name, timestamp, format, args);
        my_custom_handler(location, severity, name, timestamp, format, args);
    };

    rcutils_logging_set_output_handler(logging_multiple_output_handler);
}
```

However, this does not really work and I'm wondering what should be the best approach.
The problems are the following:

- `rcl_logging_rosout_init` is a hidden function (marked with `RCL_LOCAL`) so how can I know if rosout has been enabled without using it?
- `rcl_logging_rosout_output_handler` is not declared as hidden, but still I can't link to it for some reason.

EDIT: apparently `rcl_logging_rosout_output_handler` should be accessible and the error is linked to the following line in `rcl/CMakeLists.txt`

```
rcl_set_symbol_visibility_hidden(${PROJECT_NAME} LANGUAGE "C")
```

TICKET: https://github.com/ros2/rcl/issues/476

DISCOURSE: https://discourse.ros.org/t/set-symbol-visibility-to-hidden-for-rmw-and-rcl-packages/7981/5?u=alsora

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329532/ros2-how-to-programmatically-set-rosout-logging-handler/) by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1322 on 2019-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code I posted is supposed to work.

`rcl_logging_rosout_output_handler` is marked as `RCL_PUBLIC`, but it was not accessible due to a bug addressed by this PR https://github.com/ros2/rcl/pull/478

`rcl_logging_rosout_init` should be marked with `RCL_PUBLIC` too since otherwise the handler is useless. https://github.com/ros2/rcl/pull/479

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2019-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0